# Get random rows from sqlite database, then sort by column

Tags: database, sqlite, select, random, sql-order-by

With each new query I want to obtain a random set of 10 rows from the table `tasks`. The rows should then be sorted by column `difficulty`.

I tried this but order by `difficulty` is ignored:

```
SELECT id, difficulty
FROM tasks
ORDER BY random(), difficulty
LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First get the 10 random rows in a subquery and then sort them by `difficulty`:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT id, difficulty
  FROM tasks
  ORDER BY random()
  LIMIT 10
)
ORDER BY difficulty;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is exactly I was looking for!